# How can I access join "intermediate" table using standard django filter?

Tags: python, django, django-database

How can I get a particular queryset of RecipeIngredient instances, supposing that I know the recipe and its ingredients? Have been trying to use the following code:

```
RecipeIngredient.objects.filter(recipe=recipe, ingredient__in=recipe.ingredients.all())
```

But it returns me the queryset of one instance, but not multiple.

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name of a recipe')

    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Ingredient',
        through='RecipeIngredient',
        verbose_name='Ingredients of a recipe'
    )


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name='Name of an ingredient'
    )


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        'Recipe',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(
        'Ingredient',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    amount = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(44640)
        ],
        verbose_name='Amount of ingredients'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about that but try it.

First create a new class like:

```
class RecipeIngredientManager(models.Manager):
def function_name(self):
    return self.filter(recipe=recipe, ingredient__in=recipe.ingredients.all())
```

Then do this in the RecipeIngredient class:

```
objects = ProductManager()
```

After you have done everything makemigration and migrate:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```